# probability of getting the same permutation after swapping

Tags: probability

Given initially a sequence of numbers from `1` to `N`, uniformly choose random two numbers(can be the same element) and swap them. Repeat this operation `k` times. Ask to calculate the following two probabilities:

1. A number `t` is still in the `t`th position in the resulting sequence.
2. All numbers are in their original order, i.e. `1` to `N`.

I am not sure if a closed form solution exists. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with the assumption that $i,j$ are each chosen independently and uniformly from $\{1, \ldots n \}$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$.

For number 1, I think you can get a recurrence in $k$. Namely, if we write $T_k$ for the transposition after $k$ steps, and just take WLOG $t = 1$, then we have $$\mathbb{P}(T_{k+1}(1) = 1) = \mathbb{P}(T_{k+1}(1) = 1| T_{k}(1) = 1) \mathbb{P}(T_k(1) = 1) + \mathbb{P}(T_{k+1}(1) = 1| T_k(1) \neq 1) \mathbb{P}(T_k(1) \neq 1)$$Writing $p_k$ as shorthand for $\mathbb{P}(T_k(1) = 1)$, this is just $$p_{k+1} = \frac{n^2 - 2n}{n^2} p_k + \frac{2}{n^2}(1 - p_k)$$where for the first coefficient, there are $n^2$ total outcomes of the 2 draws from $\{1,\ldots, n\}$, $(n-1)^2$ don't involve 1, and among those involving 1, only $(1, 1)$ will leave $1$ fixed. Similarly, if $T_k(1) \neq 1$, say $WLOG$ 2, then out of all the $n^2$ possible draws, only $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ will return 1 to itself.

(Still thinking about 2)